# How to load a data in asp Grid View one by one exactly after inserted into the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, azure-web-app-service

I have a method called `processPayment`, which usually does the processing job of each client to their banking provider and write a log into the database. It works smoothly until there are more than 20 records to charge and it crashed saying timeout issues. I lost my mind here I did take a snap on my timer it will run till 2 Minutes but I provided the Timeout command for 5 Minutes. And still doesn't work.

I wonder is there any chances to show log records in the grid at the same time it processing job to the bank?
[image]

I have written a log of every transaction like this:
[image]

I think this is because of the timeout so I want to keep my connection open until is finished the whole payment process.  I believe by writing one by one in gird helps me to open my connection all the time and maybe that will resolve my issue.

Another thing that needs to keep in mind is:

> I am trying to connect from Azure (Payment Job System is running on
> the Azure) to AWS (CRM System is running on AWS in a different
> location). I need to connect to the CRM System in order to get the
> customer details and update their purchase order and receipt and many
> more.

My Method have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < JobCount; i++)
                {
                    var items = csvLists[i];
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowMessage", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('{0}')</script>", "The Payment is being proceed for : " + items["First Name"] + " " + items["Last Name"]));
                    var paymentId = items["Payment Id"];
                    var clientId = items["Client Id"];
                    var client = items["Client Name"];
                    var amount = items["Total Payment Amount"];
                    var method = items["Payment Method"];
                    AddLog(finalJobId, taskId, "Sending payment #" + i + "- Client: " + client + " - PaymentId: " + paymentId + " -  Amount: " + amount + " - Payment Method: " + method);
                                
                    //Process Actual Payment Options with Details
                    var task = ProcessPayment.Process(int.Parse(clientId), int.Parse(paymentId), serverValue);
                    AddLog(finalJobId, taskId, "Received Response  #" + i + " - Client: " + client + " - PaymentId: " + paymentId + " -  Amount: " + amount + " - Payment Method: " + method + " - Result: " + task.Result.Response);

                } 
ShowLog(finalJobId, taskId);


 public void ShowLog(int jobId, int taskId)
    {
        if (jobId <= 0) return;
        var result = DBTools.Tools().Helper.GetJobActivityByJobId(jobId);
        grdloadproperties.DataSource = result;
        grdloadproperties.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant code (with sensitive info removed)? It's difficult to repro your issue or offer suggestions without knowing what is going on in the code.

Comment: Hi @SamaraSoucy-MSFT I just update the question with code can you please have a look and let me know

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly, the for loop that processes the job is working fine, but when you call ShowLog() the database call times out?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT No I don't think so, The Issues is If I try to process the job more than 20 then it will timeout I hope but my concern is can I showLog one by one in a loop. For example, I send a job to process with 20 records and it should process 1 at a time. Could I show log that 1 record in a grid and process another job and add it to the grid again like this. is this possible?